# read kafka topics from python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

This code doesn't display any messages successfully

What's wrong?

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'topictest',
     bootstrap_servers=['server:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='None',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='test-consumer-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
for message in consumer:
    message = message.value
    print('{} added to'.format(message))
```

Comment: What do you expect `auto_offset_reset='None'` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from json import loads
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'topictest',
     bootstrap_servers=['10.17.48.245:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='latest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='test-consumer-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('ISO-8859-1')))

for message in consumer:
     print(message.value)
```

You can try without changing the encoding, as well

Comment: Why change the encoding format?

Comment: error :( JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [35], line 11
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

WARNING:kafka.coordinator:Heartbeat failed for group test-consumer-group because it is rebalancing

Comment: The issue is with the auto_offset_reset or decoding. Sometimes, the IDE or environment being used creates issues.
This is assuming that the problem is confined to reading Kafka data in Python.

Comment: @Bogdan Try changing the group_id to test-consumer-group-2

Comment: @Ritwik Bandyopadhyay changed, now there is no error, but the script is not executed for a very long time and does not display anything

Comment: @Ritwik Bandyopadhyay WARNING:kafka.coordinator:Heartbeat failed for group test-consumer-group-2 because it is rebalancing
WARNING:kafka.coordinator:Heartbeat failed for group test-consumer-group because it is rebalancing

Comment: very long execution, but there are five messages in one word

Comment: @Ritwik Bandyopadhyay

Comment: Yeah. That can happen if something keeps going into the buffer. You can maybe deduplicate it separately